# Subtrac Time and getting results in hours, minutes and seconds

Tags: excel, excel-formula

```
Check Out Date  Check out Time  Date Avail  Time Avail    Time Difference  
01/02/18    09:05:05            01/02/18    09:06:06       00:01:01
01/04/18    09:05:05            01/03/18    09:06:06       24:01:01
```

I have four columns in excel, exactly like the above table. I want the result of the formula to have the outcome like "Time Difference". I tried many methods but it doesnt work.  After I figure out how to get "Time Difference" I would like to average it. Can anyone please help?

Comment: The second example seems like it would result in negative time.

Comment: It should be check out date & time - date avail & time

Answer (score 0):

The screen-shot I've posted should answer your question (assuming I've understood it correctly).

Format your INPUT columns with one of the 'date-time' options (e.g., dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm).
This will allow you to calculate (directly) the difference between INPUT values.

Format your OUTPUT cell with the following CUSTOM format: "[hh]:mm:ss".
This will ensure your desired OUTPUT (average elapsed time) appears as a "duration", rather than a "time".

[image: Using Date/Time Entries to Calculate Duration (Excel) (Functions Shown)]

Comment: It doesnt recognize it as a date, this is the exact format for date  04/19/18 and this is the exact format for time  16:44:53  @toraritte

Comment: @Nguyenal07 Please re-clarify what you're looking for by stating which aspects of my post aren't working for you. Doing so will help me better understand what you're trying to troubleshoot. For instance, should each variable have its own column? Also, if _time_ must be formatted using _hh:mm:ss_, we'll have to come up with a work-around because it's likely being recognized as a text-string.

Comment: use custom format [h]:mm:ss or [hh]:mm:ss  for you rime format.  The [ ]  will display more than 24 hours so you wont see days.

Comment: @Nguyenal07 when you change the format of the cells holding the date from say date to general does the test change?  another test is =ISNUMBER(A2) where A2 is the cell of the date or number.  If that is false or the value in the cell does not change when the format changes, then you need to convert the text to a number first.  There are many ways to achieve this.